# Flutter I am getting a was used after disposed error when using the Chewie Video package

Tags: flutter

I am using the Chewie package to display videos: https://pub.dev/packages/chewie

All works pretty well. However when I am trying to dispose the controllers when someone backs out of the video session I am getting errors.

First here is the code I am using, its controlled by a flatbutton with a back arrow on it. Idea is to close and dispose the video screen.

```
void userExited() async {
  _chewieController.dispose();
  //dispose();
  print('USER EXITED!!');
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

However whenever I am pressing the button, I am getting a:

A ChewieController was used after being disposed.

Error message. I should point out that at no other point in my code am I calling dispose().
My question is what do i need to do to remove this error. But furthermore how to correctly dispose of the chewie video controller and close the screen without errors.

Here's the whole code:

```
class VideoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final MediaItem mediaItem;

  VideoScreen(this.mediaItem);

  @override
  _VideoScreenState createState() => _VideoScreenState();
}

class _VideoScreenState extends State<VideoScreen> {
  ChewieController _chewieController;
  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
      widget.mediaItem.itemUrl,
    );
    // Wrapper on top of the videoPlayerController
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
      //aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
      showControlsOnInitialize: false,
      fullScreenByDefault: false,
      // Prepare the video to be played and display the first frame
      autoInitialize: true,
      looping: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      // Errors can occur for example when trying to play a video
      // from a non-existent URL
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            errorMessage,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    _videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
      if (_videoPlayerController.value.position ==
          _videoPlayerController.value.duration) {
        print('video Ended');
        closeScreen();
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    });
  }


  void closeScreen() async {
    final _media = Provider.of<Media>(context, listen: false);
    _media.increasePlayCount(widget.mediaItem.id);
    final _auth = Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false);
    _media.createMediaHistory(_auth.user.uid, widget.mediaItem.id);
    dispose();
    print('VIDEO FINISHED ... CLOSE!!');
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void userExited() async {
    _chewieController.dispose();
    //dispose();
    print('USER EXITED!!');
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
           children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Chewie(
                controller: _chewieController,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: screenWidth / 20,
              top: screenWidth / 20,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  userExited();
                },
                elevation: 0.0,
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
//                backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1976D2),
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any advice on this would be really appreciated

Thanks so much

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another listener somewhere in your code? Could you copy/paste your entire code?

Comment: @GaspardMerten Hi ok I have added the complete code. Please take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dispose the controllers

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    _chewieController.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: And you should not call the dispose method manually! As soon as you pop the view, it will be automatically called. So remove the dispose() from your closeScreen method and do as @Niteesh wrote!

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes that fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
void userExited() async {
  _chewieController?.dispose();
  //dispose();
  print('USER EXITED!!');
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

or more proper way is writing dispose():

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: The ?. won't change anything since even if it was disposed of before, it does not mean that it is null!